# varnish not caching right

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to configure varnish (following by: [default_varnish3.vcl_.txt](http://www.lullabot.com/sites/lullabot.com/files/default_varnish3.vcl_.txt))

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -q varnish
varnish-3.0.3-1.el5.centos.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

I'm making a very first hit through my browser (page loads fine), then I do it again through curl on my local machine:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ curl -I alexustest:6081
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1800
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 19:27:15 +0000
Expires: Sun, 11 Mar 1984 12:00:00 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 19:27:16 GMT
X-Varnish: 1355259954
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org
X-Cache: MISS
```

it shows me `X-Cache: MISS`, when it really should have been a HIT (since this is second hit), so I do it again (3rd time and again from my Linux workstation).

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ curl -I alexustest:6081
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1800
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 19:27:15 +0000
Expires: Sun, 11 Mar 1984 12:00:00 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 19:27:19 GMT
X-Varnish: 1355259955 1355259954
Age: 3
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1

[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

and now it's a HIT, it sounds like it's caching per client or something. As I said I'm using [default_varnish3.vcl_.txt](http://www.lullabot.com/sites/lullabot.com/files/default_varnish3.vcl_.txt), so you can see my configuration as that, I only changed backend information to match my environment and also added following code (to produce HIT/MISS):

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 varnish]# cat vcl_deliver/resp.vcl 
set resp.http.X-Served-By = server.hostname;
if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";  
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
} else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS"; 
}
[root@wcmisdlin02 varnish]#
```

*** UPDATE ***

varnishncsa's:

```
10.52.208.221 - - [11/Apr/2013:15:45:35 -0400] "HEAD http://alexustest:6081/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2"
10.100.0.35 - - [11/Apr/2013:15:45:38 -0400] "HEAD http://alexustest:6081/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5"
```

Comment: Can you post some logfiles from varnish.  Firstly the NCSA log details, and also the Varnish transactional log..

Comment: please see my update: this is me through to do it via curl from two different place, and actually on second time I got HIT as well (so that worked fine), I also noticed that whenever I'm doing it from browser it does GET instead of HEAD, does it make difference in terms of caching or not?

Comment: It shouldn't.  I suspect a GET is more likely to be cached, as it's actually retrieving more than just the headers.. I'm not convinced you can warm the cache suitably by just HEADing paths.

Answer (score 1):

> first hit through my browser (page loads fine), then I do it again through curl

But you told the webcache you were going to serve different results based on the cookies and the content encoding:

> Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding

Did you delete all the cookies in your browser before before the first request? Also how did you make the request from the browser - a reload has very different behaviour from a refresh.

(BTW if you're going to vary your by cookie and you're using sessions then you should make your cache controlprovate - otherwise you're making Varnish work hard for no benefit, indeed you could actually slow your site down).

Comment: would you mind explain a little bit more? goal is simple: let varnish serve content as much as possible without reaching out to backend server.

Comment: Then don't add a 'vary' header.

Comment: Where do I add 'vary'? I've search my entire config I don't see 'vary' anywhere...

Comment: On the webserver / application tier

Comment: I have "Header unset ETag" on my backend (apache) server, but maybe this isn't same thing that you're referring. I read it from Drupal's varnish module instruction somewhere..

Comment: it is really weird how it's working though, because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, i'm so confused(